# I want to display an animated GIF on the splash screen of iOS with ReactNative (or want to have the same behavior)

Tags: ios, react-native, splash-screen, gif, animated-gif

As the title says, I want to display animated GIFs on the iOS splash screen.
However, I saw a lot of information that the iOS splash screen does not support animated GIFs.
If you know how to achieve a splash screen-like behavior on iOS, could you give me some advice?
Of course, it also supports Android, so I think that a method that can be realized on Android is good.
Sorry for poor English.

react-native: 0.60.6

Thank you.

Comment: Splash can be loaded from a xib file in iOS. design a xib and use it as splash screen, you will be able to animate your gif.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I am going to use it as an example.

Comment: You cannot animate in any `LaunchScreen` files in Xcode yet. Using an xib file does not allow gifs.

Answer (score 0):

@gysnet use **react-native-community/lottie-react-native**

> https://github.com/react-native-community/lottie-react-native

Comment: Thank you for the information. I am going to use it as an example.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately as far as I am aware RN only allows the splash screen content to be static, however there are workarounds.

I was able to get around it by first setting a standard static splash screen, and then having that transition into an initial screen containing the animated splash on a timeout.

There is a good example of how you can do this here:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MY6rE5plNIc

Comment: It is not what that was asked in the question (animated gif)

Comment: The process is the same whether it's an animated gif, video, or whatever other content you would like to display.

You cannot put an animated gif as the native iOS splash, however you can create a regular react component that the iOS splash will transition to, creating the illusion of a native splash.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using lottie instead of gif, i would suggest looking into this package.

> https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-lottie-splash-screen

It implements animation splash screen using airbnb lottie files in react native. Also, I apply this for multiple react native projects and it worked well.

Have a nice day!

Comment: Even this package cannot display a gif in the `LaunchScreen.storyboard`. It displays the animation after the launch screen, like the answer GrapeJam gave. That should be the accepted answer. It is not possible to load an animated launch screen in iOS yet.